# How can I start an UWP application through a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-10, cross-window-scripting

I tried to open **Skype** using batch scripting (.bat) in Windows 10 but found that in Windows 10 Skype came as default and it is **moved to Windows Apps**. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, find the application's install location and package family name by running the following in PowerShell:

```
Get-AppxPackage | Select Name, InstallLocation, PackageFamilyName
```

Skype's name is `Microsoft.SkypeApp`, its install location is something like `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.SkypeApp_12.1815.210.0_x64__kzf8qxf38zg5c` and its package family name is `Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c`.

Browse to the install location and open the `AppxManifest.xml` in a text editor. Find the `<Application ...>` node and get the value of the `Id` property. For Skype, this value is `App`.

Now you can use these values in this command:

```
start shell:AppsFolder\<PackageFamilyName>!<Id>
```

For Skype, you'd run:

```
start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked for me for me also found same kind of path and also id value as **app**

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked for me for me also found same kind of path and also id value as **app**                                                                                                        
 start **shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_14.33.41.0_x64__kzf8qxf38zg5c!App**                _showing error that windows cannot find 'shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_14.33.41.0_x64__kzf8qxf38zg5c!App'. Make sure you typed name correctly._

Comment: There shouldn't be a version number in the command. You need the package family name. What happens if you use `start shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c!App`?

Comment: This works for WinUI 3 packaged app